# Getting firebase Realtime database value in syncfusion_flutter_gauges but getting error using stream builder

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, flutter-getx

I am currently working on an app in which I take value from firebase realtime database an put it in syncfusion_flutter_gauges for radial gauge meter but keep getting error.
trying to fetch data from firebase realtime database, [image]
Please tell me how to solve this?
this is my code:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: StreamBuilder<DatabaseEvent>(
            stream: databaseReference.child('test').child('gasValue').onValue,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                Object? value = snapshot.data!.snapshot.value;
                return SfRadialGauge(
                  axes: [
                    RadialAxis(
                      minimum: 0,
                      maximum: 100,
                      showLabels: false,
                      showTicks: false,
                      axisLineStyle: AxisLineStyle(
                        thickness: 0.1,
                        cornerStyle: CornerStyle.bothCurve,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        thicknessUnit: GaugeSizeUnit.factor,
                      ),
                      pointers: const [
                        NeedlePointer(
                           value: value,  //getting error here....!
                          needleLength: 0.7,
                          needleColor: Colors.red,
                          needleStartWidth: 1,
                          needleEndWidth: 5,
                          knobStyle: KnobStyle(
                            knobRadius: 0.09,
                            sizeUnit: GaugeSizeUnit.factor,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                      annotations: [
                        GaugeAnnotation(
                          widget: Text(
                            value.toString(),
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 25,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                          angle: 90,
                          positionFactor: 0.5,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
              } else {
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Please Help..!

Comment: I am currently at latest flutter version 3.7.3

Comment: can you add the error message what is the error

Answer (score 1):

You are defining `value` as `Object?` but in the NeedlePointer widget `value` is most likely of type `int`. From your code and not seeing your database structure, I would guess that the `value` returned from the database is either of type `int` or of type `Map<String, dynamic>`. You therefore need to treat it as such by e.g. casting  the returned result to `int` or `Map<String, dynamic>` using `as`.

For example:
`final value = snapshot.data!.snapshot.value! as int;`

You should really also be testing for the returned value not being null, or your will get a runtime error on the `.value!' if it is.

Finally, you should be assigning your stream to a variable either in initState (means you need this to be a Stateful widget) or declaring it with the stream contents, and using that variable as the `stream:` parameter. Otherwise, you are recreating this stream everytime the page rebuilds.

Update based on comment...

The build method can run many times for many reasons. Each time it runs, the stream in your code will be reinitialized and will reload data from the database that you already have, instead of it just loading new database events, as you intend it to do.

To avoid this you should create a variable as follows and then use the variable as your stream value...

```
 final streamVar = databaseReference.child('test').child('gasValue').onValue;
```

Comment: Thankyou for your guidance but can you explain the stream part more

Comment: It is still giving me this error....    A value of type 'Null' can't be assigned to a parameter of type 'double' in a const constructor.

Comment: the value in database is int

Comment: So that error says to me that 
the  NeedlePointer  value parameter expects a double, not an int and that you are giving it a null value. You are going to have to use print statements and/or your IDE debugger to find out what is actually going on. That's down to you, mate.